# Is proper time the affine parameter in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, time, geodesics

If we consider the proper time, $\gamma d\tau = dt$, and 4-velocity $v^{\mu}=\tfrac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}=(\gamma c,\gamma \vec{v})$ of a particle with velocity $\vec{v}$, then the corresponding space-time interval is being travelled through at constant speed $-c^2$ according to the Minkowski metric $(-,+,+,+)$, i.e.
$$
\eta(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}) = -\gamma^2c^2 + \gamma^2v^2 = -c^2.
$$

But then, in the presence of a gravitational field, such speed is replaced by $g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v})$, which is not necessarily equal to $-c^2$ (i.e. not necessarily constant).

So, in the geodesic equation, which has affine parametrization (i.e. constant speed)
$$
\dfrac{d^2x^{\mu}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\beta\gamma}\dfrac{dx^{\beta}}{ds}\dfrac{dx^{\gamma}}{ds} = 0.\tag{1} 
$$

is the parameter $s$ not equal to the proper time $\tau$? Is $\tfrac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$ not equal to the four-velocity?

And what about a free-falling frame of reference? Such a on observer would measure
$$
\dfrac{d^2x^{\mu}}{d\tilde{s}^2} = 0.
$$

would we write $d\tilde{s}=d\tau$ in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

1. The affine geodesic equation (1) is invariant precisely under [affine reparametrizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) (with non-zero slope), i.e. any 2 parametrizations are related by an affine reparametrization.

   For this reason the parametrizations of (1) are called affine parametrizations.

   Concerning non-affine parametrizations, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760155/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. For a timelike geodesic, the proper time is an example of an affine parametrization. (Proper time cannot be used to parametrize null/light-like geodesics.)